# AVL tree Height Method StackOverFlow Erroe

Tags: java

I am trying to implement AVL tree.I'm having stackOverFlow on height method. I tried with small number of inputs it works. However, When i tried with large scale of input, it crush. Here is my code.

```
   private int height(Node<T> node){

      if(!isEmpty() && node != null){
          if(isleaf(node))
            return 1;
         else{
            int p = height(node.left);
            int q = height(node.right);
            if(p > q)
                return p + 1;
            else 
                return q + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the tree is valid? Also, how does isEmpty work? There might be a recursion cycle there. And can you post the stack trace so we can see  what's going on?

Comment: isEmpty is boolean method ,return root == null.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at ATree.height(ATree.java:35)     //int p = height(node.left);
         at ATree.height(ATree.java:36) .  // int q = height(node.right);

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your tree has cyclic references. Check tree construction. To debug - assign unique values and print while traversing the nodes.

Comment: I think you are right. The file i am trying to read there are lots of duplicate numbers. My AVL works up to certain inputs then it crush. Is there any way to handle duplicate in AVL Tree?

Comment: There is a problem with your code piece which is creating and reusing node  objects. You should create new instance for each node. Reusing will create a cyclic reference.